# how to extract the first td passcode from below response in postman

Tags: html, postman

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>OTP Msisdn-Passcode Mapping</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>One-Time Passcode: Mapping of MSISDN to Generated Passcode</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>MSISDN</th>
                <th>Passcode</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="msisdn">MSISDN</td>
                <td class="passcode">742336</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="msisdn">MSISDN</td>
                <td class="passcode">424151</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using below which is concatenating values. I want to add first passcode in one variable and other passcode in second variable.

```
const responseHTML = cheerio.load(responseBody);
pm.globals.set('otpCode', responseHTML('td[class="passcode"]').text());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like this but it's very much hardcoded to specific rows and data in a table:

```
pm.globals.set('otpCode_1', responseHTML('tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)').text());
pm.globals.set('otpCode_2', responseHTML('tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)').text());
```